# Menu Cuts Off In View Item SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, view-item

I have a SP 2010 list that when I try to View an item the menu cuts off at the top shown below:

[image]

I performed a test and created a new custom list. I then added a new item, Viewed the item and the menu does NOT cut off at the top.

It seems to only occur in the specific list. Anyone have an idea as to why it does that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the F12 Developer Tools in Internet Explorer and check what CSS is applied to the element. It looks as if some CSS setting is preventing the ribbon row or the ribbon container to be cropped at the top instead of showing at full height.